# Angular material 4 virtual repeat

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hello does the virtual repeat component also exists in angular 4?

I need to show a dropdown menu with autocomplete with lots of data (30k elements) and angular material mat-autocomplete doesn't do the trick.

Comment: When it's autocomplete, why don't you just limit the number of results. I don't think anybody would want to scroll over 30k elements in an autocomplete.

Comment: I would do that also, but the users want it that way..

Comment: Poor you. But also seems that the problem the users are facing might be better solved by a different approach. Like a alphabetiacally grouped item tree.

Comment: I meant to say that not always when a user describes a solution to a problem, is she really describing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for the moment

credits: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

It is used like this

```
<ng-select [items]="items" [virtualScroll]="true" 
           bindLabel="Description"bindValue="Id" placeholder="Select city" 
           [(ngModel)]="text">
</ng-select>
```

Then add the material theme to your styles.

@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css";